# Bootstrap multiple choice

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to bootstrap a mulitple choice tickbox for PHP. I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<form action="catcheck.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But im just getting a normal checkbox, how do I go about changing this to submit to catcheck.php whilst using the bootstrap css?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean there, but you should at least give your submit button a value: <input type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: Im trying to have a Bootstrap multiple choice that submits the data to PHP (using $_POST or similar)

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work (Hope this is what you needed):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <form action="catcheck.php" method="post" role="form">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1" /> Value 1
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 2" /> Value 2
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 3" /> Value 3
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 4" /> Value 4
                        </label>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In catcheck.php

You can retrieve data as `$_POST['check_list']` which will return an `array`. You can begin from:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

**EDIT:**

The below code will do what you have asked (with doc reference)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1" />
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="text_value[]" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 2" />
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="text_value[]" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 3" />
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="text_value[]" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 4" />
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="text_value[]" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

For alignment consider the following CSS:

```
.input-group
{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

You can adjust the size of input area by reducing `col-lg-6` to `col-lg-4` and so on.

Fiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/27LnT/

Comment: Is it possible to get the text as shown in the Bootstrap documentation? [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios)

Comment: This looks correct in the jsfiddle, do you know why mine are coming up like so: [image](http://i.imgur.com/B0HlLLE.png)

Comment: That's because you would have used Bootstrap 2.3.2 CSS. The question and my answer were related to Bootstrap 3.0.2. Just replace the CSS file